# Why C++ and Python bitwise shift operator result are diffrernt?

Tags: python, c++, bit-manipulation

why the result of C++ and python bitwise shift operator are diffrernt?
python

```
>>> 1<<20
1048576
```

C++

```
cout <<1<<20;
120
```

Comment: `cout << (1<<20);`.  You're not bit shifting, you're just sending '1' and '20' to cout.  You're mixing the output operator and the bit shift operator.

Comment: In C++ you'd want this: `cout << (1<<20);`. C++ is a *context sensitive* language. The same symbols mean different things in different contexts (and can even be overloaded to gain entirely new, user-defined, meaning)

Comment: Note that (1 << 20) is UB in C++ for a 16 bit `int`.

Answer (score 5):

The result differes because of the operator associativity in C++.

```
std::cout << 1 << 20;
```

is the same as

```
(std::cout << 1) << 20;
```

because `operator <<` is left-associative. What you intend to do is

```
std::cout << (1 << 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

cout overloads the '<<' operator to print the values. So when you are doing

```
cout <<1<<20;
```

It actually prints 1 and 20 and doesnt do any shifting

```
int shifted = 1 << 20;
cout << shifted;
```

This should return the same output as python's

simpler way is to do

```
cout << (1 <<20);
```